# MongoDB: delete object elements with condition on the key

Tags: mongodb

Given the following documents in Mongo:

```js
[
  {
  "_id": "1",
  "prices": {
    "2024-01-01 00:00:00": "11",
    "2024-01-02 00:00:00": "22",
    "2024-01-03 00:00:00": "33"
    },
  }
  {
  "_id": "2",
  "prices": {
    "2024-01-03 00:00:00": "33",
    "2024-01-04 00:00:00": "44",
    "2024-01-05 00:00:00": "55"
    }
  }
]
```

I need to support two operations:

- Update price element by date (e.g. set `"$.prices.2024-01-01 00:00:00" = 100`).
- Delete all elements in `prices` object with a condition on the key date (e.g. delete all elements where `$.prices.key <= "2024-01-01 00:00:00"`).

I am not sure how can I do the second operation in an efficient way using Mongo. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the second question, one option is to use update with pipeline, with `arrayToObject` and `$objectToArray`:

```
db.collection.update(
  {},
  [{$set: {
      prices: {
        $arrayToObject: {
          $filter: {
            input: {$objectToArray: "$prices"},
            cond: {$gt: [{$toDate: "$$this.k"}, date]} // you can use string if you want
          }
        }
      }
  }}],
  {multi: true}
)
```

See How it works on the [mongoDB playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/K_0ztzomHkR)

Comment: Thanks a lot, very helpful! For the first operation I was thinking to use just a simple $set operation: `$set: { "prices.2023-01-01 00:00:00": "11111" }`